# Why do I get an invalid block crash when deleting objects involved in multiple (virtual) inheritance?

Tags: c++, crash, destructor, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance

I'm editing this question to make it more readable and less contrived. I've managed to replicate my issue with the following short piece of code. The question, then, is: why does this crash on an assertion failure with _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse) on the "delete p" line in ~A()?

```
class A;

class I
{
public:
    I(const A *p) : parent_(p) {}

    virtual void foo() = 0;
protected:
    const A *parent_;
};

class I1 : public virtual I
{
public:
    I1(const A *p) : I(p) {}

    virtual void foo() {}
};

class A
{
public:
    A() {}
    virtual ~A()
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < it_.size(); ++i)
        {
            I *p = it_.at(i);
            delete p;
        }
    }

    virtual I* add() { I *p = new I1(this); it_.push_back(p); return p; }
protected:
    vector<I*> it_;
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    A *a = new A();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) a->add();
    delete a;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As per @James Kanze's suggestion, adding an empty virtual destructor for class I solved the problem in relation to this example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the destructor of `SeqItem` virtual?  If not, you have undefined behavior; in practice, this undefined behavior will only display immediate disasterous results if multiple inheritance is involved, and even then, not necessarily unless the inheritance is virtual.  (Without multiple inheritance, it will typically seem to work, although it will often leak memory.)

Comment: No, SeqItem only has a single int as a member, so I didn't make a destructor for it. Actually, none of the classes in the SeqItem hierarchy have them, since they only store regular members like ints and strings.

Comment: If you delete an object, either the static type and the dynamic type must be identical, or the object type must have a virtual destructor (even if this destructor doesn't do anything).  If you're deleting through a `SeqItem*`, and the actual type of the object is some derived class, `SeqItem` must have a virtual destructor, or the behavior is undefined.

Comment: I had absolutely no idea, I never would've thought an empty destructor would've made a diferrence. Anyway, this was spot on, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Haven't read the entire Question but first off Destructor in `Sequence` class should be marked `virtual`.

```
virtual ~Sequence();
```

If destructor of your polymorphic Base class is not `virtual` then you have a Undefined Behavior looming when deleting a derived class object through Base class pointer.

Comment: Sorry for the long question, but I wrote that changing the base destructor to virtual was one of the things I tried to remedy the situation and it still crashes. :(

Answer (score 0):

you need to derive from base class virtually - that is

```
class SeqItemB : virtual public SeqItemA { .. }
class SeqItemC : virtual public SeqItemA { .. }
```

and then

```
class SeqItemD : public SeqItemB, public SeqItemC { .. }
```

Comment: That's exactly how I wrote it. Ommited for the sake of brevity (question is long anwyay)...